# mongodb expected to be write locked

Tags: mongodb, locking, assertion

I have the following thing showing in my logs:

```
[conn70] assertion 16105 expected to be write locked for monitoring ns:monitoring.notifications query:{ $query: { notification_id: "401", date_created: /2014-11-14/ }, $orderby: { date_created: 1 } }
```

Can't find any information about 16105 and i've never worked with Mongo before, but need to fix that as soon as possible.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you got MMS or anything installed?

Comment: No, any suggestions about helpful tool for debugging/monitoring?

Comment: I did a little searching and found: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11294 same assertion but for different reason

Comment: Thanks, saw that before writing but it looks different. I'll check it again just to be sure.

Comment: If so it is definitely worth throwing this onto the JIRA, it might be that you have some monitoring program/command running and it conflicted or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find why this happens, but it okay after update do 2.6 - at least for now everything is running fine.